# Using Haskell's SimpleHTTP with a Proxy?

Tags: networking, haskell, proxy

I'm trying to figure out how make a basic GET request using Network.HTTP.simpleHTTP that will use a proxy.

I have tried setting the http_proxy environment variable, and I think I understand how to make a Proxy using Network.HTTP.Proxy.  But there seems to be nothing in the API on Hackage for how to set a simpleHTTP call or Request type to use a proxy.

The current code I have is:

```
import Network.HTTP
import Network.HTTP.Proxy
import Data.Maybe

main = do 
   let proxy = fromJust $ parseProxy "proxyserver.foo.com:80"
   x <- simpleHTTP (getRequest "http://www.google.com") >>= getResponseBody
   print x
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HTTP/4000.0.9/doc/html/Network-HTTP.html) for `simpleHTTP`:

> `simpleHTTP req` transmits the `Request req` by opening a *direct*,
>   non-persistent connection to the HTTP
>   server... 
>   If you have to mediate the request via
>   an HTTP proxy, you will have to
>   normalize the request yourself. Or
>   switch to using `Network.Browser`
>   instead.

I'm not really sure what the authors mean by "normalize the request yourself" here. I don't see how it would be possible with the `simpleHTTP` in `Network.HTTP`—I think you'd have to use the one in [`Network.HTTP.HandleStream`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HTTP/4000.0.9/doc/html/Network-HTTP-HandleStream.html).

So why not just use `Network.Browser` instead? It's very handy:

```
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)
import Network.Browser
import Network.HTTP
import Network.HTTP.Proxy (parseProxy)

main = do
  rsp <- browse $ do
    setProxy . fromJust $ parseProxy "127.0.0.1:8118"
    request $ getRequest "http://www.google.com"
  print $ rspBody <$> rsp
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked first try. Yeah, I saw that 'normalize' comment in the API shortly after posting but didn't have clue how to do it either.